# How to turn on the FULLTEXT mode on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I'm currently trying to create FULLTEXT indexes into my database (Microsoft SQL Server 2005).

First I want to create the catalog:

```
USE [AspDotNetStorefront]
GO
EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG searchcatalog 
GO
```

But that doesn't work, the result is this:

```
Msg 7609, Level 17, State 100, Line 1
Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.
```

I'm running on Windows XP, SQL Server Express 9.0.4053 and I have SQL Server Management Studio Express (9.0).

Comment: I've searched where I could install it or add the component but nothing :(

Comment: It appears that the FTS is not installed, I tried to Modify the installation (in Add or Remove Programs) and to run the installation process again, it never asked me for the component... Or the components list was empty (if it was supposed to be there).

Comment: please use the system recommended "sql-server" and "sql-server-2005" tags instead of "mssql" - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full-Text search is only available in the SQL  Express Advanced versions, see [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx). Get 2005 from [Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4C6BA9FD-319A-4887-BC75-3B02B5E48A40&displaylang=en), 2008 from [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b5d1b8c3-fda5-4508-b0d0-1311d670e336&displaylang=en)