# Fuzzy search in SQL

Tags: sql, fuzzy-search

I am trying to map information of Linux packages (name + version) to their corresponding CPE strings (see http://nvd.nist.gov/cpe.cfm) in order to be able to automatically find possible vulnerabilities of a system.

There is an XML document provided by NIST which contains all relevant CPE. I thought about parsing this information into an SQL database so I can quickly search by name and version number. That would be some 70.000 rows.

The problem now is, of course, that there are variations of the spellings of the CPEs and the package names. For example, the CPE for Tomcat 6.0.36 would be `cpe:/a:apache:tomcat:6.0.36` so you have the name `tomcat` and the version `6.0.36`. Now, the package manager could give you something like `tomcat6` for the name and `6.0.36-3` for the version. Its likely that both programs are the same or have at least the same vulnerabilities. So I need to be able to automatically identify the above mentioned CPE as the correct one for my tomcat package.

The first thing to do would be some kind of normalization, maybe converting everything to lowercase. But as you can see from the example, that's not enough. I need some kind of fuzzy search. From what I already found out, there are some solutions for identifying matches in the case of misspelling. That is not exactly what I need, though. The package names are not misspelled but may contain additional characters (or miss some).

The fuzzy search must also be relatively fast, since I need to execute it for multiple hosts which each could have some hundred packages installed and as I said, the database would have around 70.000 rows. I can introduce a primary lookup which tries to find an exact match first, but since I suspect many package will not have any corresponding CPE string, that will not decrease the amount too dramatically.

Another constraint is that the solution should be working on a non-proprietary database, since I don't have the financial means for anything else.

So, is there anything that matches these requirements? Or can you think of any solution to my problem except some kind of fuzzy searching?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I'd be more tempted by "normalising" on import into my database. So have some function to come up with unique CPE whne you import the list and can do the same for a search target. That way you take a single hit and can use a straight search as though exact match was okay, instead of getting all fuzzy for every compare.

Answer (score 2):

A general comment, first. The CPE nomenclature seems to have evolved organically, often depending on the vendors' (inconsistent) nomenclature. For example, Sun Java has major.minor.point_version. Adobe uses major.minor.point.subpoint. Microsoft operating systems use Service Packs_Language Packs. Some other vendors would use point releases with mostly numbers but occasional letters sprinkled in (e.g., .8, .9, .9R2, .10).

When I worked on the stated problem, I started from their XML files and manipulated them in Excel, splitting on the periods. Then I would sort either numerically (if they were all numeric) or as a text string. (Note that the letters sprinkled in to mostly numbers causes havoc, and that .10 comes lexically before .8)

This inconsistency is why third-party software vendors have sprouted like mushrooms after a spring rain. Companies would rather pay the software vendors than untangle this Gordian knot.

If you want a truly fuzzy search, please take a look at this question about [using Soundex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1923394/509840). Expect to get a lot of false positives.

If your goal is accurately mapping the CPE strings, you should probably think about implementing a lookup table that translates from CPE to a library name.