# SQL find Word in String (any Spelling)

Tags: sql

I want to find a word in a string with SQL. I currently use:

```
SELECT * FROM dreams
WHERE 
    title 
LIKE '%lo%'
```

But I want also to find other spellings like "Lo" or "LO" and so on..

Any Ideas ?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I only know mySQL, and in that case you would need to configure a new database to be case sensitive. There is a also a REGEXP implemented that I'd bet is fairly universal.

Comment: Not necessarily - using the OR operator in the MySQL query would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert it to upper case before comparing

```
SELECT * FROM dreams
WHERE 
    upper(title) 
LIKE '%LO%'
```

Comment: I'm not convinced his query is case-sensitive... mine normally return case-insensitive results... need the server to know.

Comment: That one worked for me! Thanks a lot.
And thanks to the others as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM dreams WHERE title LIKE '%lo%'
union
SELECT * FROM dreams WHERE title LIKE '%LO%'
union
SELECT * FROM dreams WHERE title LIKE '%Lo%';
```

Comment: If case-insensitive, this will return the same results for all three, giving 3*duplicate results... maybe SELECT * FROM dreams WHERE title LIKE '%lo%' OR title LIKE '%LO%' OR title LIKE '%Lo%';

Comment: @CLaFarge: no it will not return duplicates because `UNION` will remove them. `UNION ALL` would keep duplicates. But I do agree that this is not the most efficient way to do this. Ramana's solution is the right one.

Comment: Nice to know... I'd still use one query, given the opportunity. In fact, I think I'd use something like: SELECT * FROM dreams WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE '%lo%';

Answer (score 0):

We have no idea what version of SQL, but here's a [very possibly related post on SOundex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064445/sql-fuzzy-matching), and [another on Full Text Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923394/use-soundex-word-by-word-on-sql-server), a [page on CONTAINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx).

The more info you provide, the better able we are to help.

I hope that SOUNDEX, or Full Text Searching, or CONTAINS, alternatively, are useful to you.